# How to make a touchable graphical object in an Android application?

Tags: android, graphics, view, touch, shapes

I want to put some graphical shapes (e.g., a character, some moving objects, etc.) in a big view, and being able to touch them.

What should I use ?
-  A drawable object is simple to draw but it can't be attached to a touch listener. How can I detect a click in the bounds of my shape ?
- With views, I can use a touch listener, but is it a good idea to use views to draw graphics in a game ? Aren't they better for forms ? Also, I want to put those shapes anywhere on the screen (absolute position). I cannot find a way to do this with views.

Thank a lot.

Comment: I asked a similar question a while back about clicking/dragging a custom view around, and I got a great response that solved it for me. My app had VERY simple graphics and controls, but the performance was great. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2363666/android-drag-animation-of-views

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you would want to draw the objects within a single view (your drawable object method) and then use a touch listener on that encompassing view. In that listener, you would compare the touch position to the positions/bounds of the objects you are drawing - and if the touch would qualify as being 'on' an interactive object, you would then handle it accordingly.