# What's the code to drag a rectangle around the screen?

Tags: java, android, drag-and-drop, coordinates

I drew a rectangle and I want to have it move with my finger. I have everything except the logic behind changing the coordinates of the vertices as I move my finger.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out [this](http://blahti.wordpress.com/2011/01/17/moving-views-part-2/) post or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2363666/android-drag-animation-of-views) question?