# Grid View Animation only on child view's

Tags: android, gridview, animation

How to apply animation on gridview's child view while we drag the child view and reorder the child dynamically with animation?

Incase you dont understand the my requirement have a look at this
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X984r7IOrgc

I have referred [Android Drag/Animation of Views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2363666/android-drag-animation-of-views) but it explains for the independent view.

Thanks for Help!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you look at GridLayoutAnimationController? Or LayoutAnimation in general?
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/GridLayoutAnimationController.html

Looking at the YouTube, it is possible that these are RenderAnimation rather than Layout.

Comment: Is there any sample on how to use GridLayoutAnimationController?

Comment: Hi kenny Lim is there any link or any tutorial understand this thing?