# View that can be moved with a finger

Tags: android, android-layout

I try to implement an Android App for tablets where you can move around a textbox on the screen with your finger. I'm wondering if there is already a predefined View in the Android SDK that has this function. Like a draggable view, but without the drag and drop functionality (or for those who know Microsoft Surface, I search something like the ScatterView in the MS Surface SDK).
Or if somebody knows a good tutorial how to build such a view, that would be of great help too.

I hope you understand what I am searching for.

Thanks for your help.
The Dude

Comment: I think this answer is valid for your question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2363666/android-drag-animation-of-views

Comment: Thanks for this link. But when I use it, I can only move around the image in my view, but not the view on the screen. I would like to move the whole view around.